# How to deny and allow access certain path/directory/file based on IP Address without changing codes?

Tags: asp.net, iis

How to do this without changing codes? Like using web.config or on IIS? I found  but it looks like it is site-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use roles and give access accordingly for set of pages?

However there is a **IP Address and Domain Restrictions** modules in IIS that can be used at site/folder/file level.

So say you have a website **samplewebsite** hosted on IIS which has a folder **Content** and a file **test.aspx**.

1. Open IIS manager expand the site and select the folder
2. Click on **IP Address and Domain Restrictions** => On the right side you can see Add Allow Entry/Add Deny Entry.
3. Clicking on it opens a pop-up where you can add your rule to restrict specific IP by adding a deny rule.

The rules you add here will go to applicationhost.config (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config) and not your web.config. A sample deny rule will look like below -

```
<location path="samplewebsite/Content">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity>
                <add ipAddress="10.0.0.1" allowed="false" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If you want to do the same thing for a page

1. Open IIS manager expand the site and select the folder
2. Now on the bottom you can see **Content View** (More info about Content View here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library /cc771124%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Click on the Content View and that will list all the files inside that folder.
3. Right click on the file you want to restrict and click on **Switch to Features View** . Now you can see all the modules and follow the same steps above to add a rule.

I am not really sure if this is the best approach as IP restrictions are recommended to be at site/server level.